# Drag stuttering with React

Tags: reactjs, drag

I'm trying to implement a simple draggable SVG handle with React. I am getting a stuttering effect if I drag the element too fast. I've tried to add checks to make sure that the element is not getting rendered more than it should and those seemed to have helped, but there is still a noticeable stutter. Anyone have any experience with this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tympit?file=App.tsx

Comment: Have you tried moving the window listener events inside of a useEffect instead of it being inside the function itself ? worth a shot.

Comment: Adding your event listeners inside your useEffect as BARNOWL mentionned would prevent the redefinition of your listener on every render, make sure to add your `dragging` as a parameter of the useEffect. (Not 100% sure however).

Comment: The listeners are only being added on mouse down. I'm not seeing where I could put the useEffect you mention

Comment: I tried implementing in vanilla JS and still seems to stutter. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-knjrbo?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the condition `newX % step === 0`. When removing the condition and calling onChange with `onChange(roundNearest(newX, step));` with roundNearest defined as:

```js
function roundNearest(num: number, step: number) {
  return Math.round(num / step) * step;
}
```

It runs smoothly

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tympit?file=App.tsx